# NDSolveValue to Manipulate Plot

Tags: plotting

There is my code

```
 Clear["Global'*"]
Greg1[tmax_, k_, R_, J_, m_, \[Theta]0_, \[Omega]0_] :=
 NDSolveValue[
  {(J + m*R)*\[Theta]''[t] == -(1/4)*k*R*\[Theta][t],
   \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0,
   \[Theta]'[0] == \[Omega]0
   },
  \[Theta],
  {t, 0, tmax}
  ]

sol1 = Greg1[10, 800, 0.5, 20, 100, \[Pi]/16, 0]



  Plot[
 sol1[\[FormalX]],
 {\[FormalX], 0., 10.},
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Theta](t)"},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}
 ]
```

And the graph looked like this
[image]

I need to make interactive plot using manipulate.
How can I make it??

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 sol1 = greg1[tmax, k, R0, J0, m, \[Theta]0 Degree, \[Omega]0  Degree];

 Plot[sol1[t], {t, 0., tmax}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"\[Theta](t)", None}, {"t", "my solution"}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 400],

 {{tmax, 10, "tmax"}, .1, 50, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{k, 800, "k"}, 10, 2000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{R0, 0.5, "R"}, 0.1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{J0, 20, "J"}, 1, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{m, 100, "m"}, 10, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 Delimiter,
 {{\[Theta]0, 30, "\[Theta](0) degree"}, 0, 180, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{\[Omega]0, 0, "\[Omega]0(0) degree/sec"}, 0, 180, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},

 TrackedSymbols :> {tmax, k, R0, J0, m, \[Theta]0, \[Omega]0},

 Alignment -> Center, SynchronousUpdating -> True, 
 SynchronousInitialization -> True, FrameMargins -> 1, 
 ImageMargins -> 1, ControlPlacement -> Left,
 Initialization :>
  (
   greg1[tmax_, k_, R0_, J0_, m_, \[Theta]0_, \[Omega]0_] := 
    Module[{\[Theta], t},
     NDSolveValue[{(J0 + m*R0)*\[Theta]''[t] == -(1/4)*k*
         R0*\[Theta][t], \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0, \[Theta]'[
         0] == \[Omega]0}, \[Theta], {t, 0, tmax}]
     ]
   )
 ]
```